# Get only unique values in each list in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a nested list:

```
a=[[2, 3], [2], [3,4], [1, 2]]
```

I want to remove repeated values from other lists in the nested list such that 'a' will become

```
a = [[3], [2], [4], [1]]
```

Comment: What's the logic? Why can't `[2, 3], [], [4], [1]]` be the output? Or `[[], [], [3, 4], [1, 2]]`?

Comment: If all you want is the unique items, add each sublist entry to a set.  Easy peasy.  `uniq = set(k for l in a for k in l)`.